# A plugin class should not have a constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

While studying the [Plug & Paint Basic Tools Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaintplugins-basictools-example.html), I've noted [the class which implements the plugin interface have no constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaintplugins-basictools-basictoolsplugin-h.html).

1. A plugin class should not have a constructor?
2. This means it also should not have a desctructor?
3. If it has a constructor, when it gets called?
4. What should be put in a plugin class constructor?
5. A `virtual void init() = 0` in the plugin interface will be an alternative to a constructor?

Comment: Do you need a constructor? You're implementing an interface with no constructors.

Comment: If, some kind of initialization seems needed then perhaps an `init()` would do (kind of) the constructor job. Is that the idea? Or, perhaps, any kind of initialization in a plugin should be a smell of inapropriate design?

Comment: If you really need to initialize variables, then both options are right, though I'd prefer to use a constructor. In my case, I'm not used to seeing constructors or member variables in Qt plugins but I suppose it depends on your requirements.

Comment: I had some issue while loading a plugin statically, where the things inside the constructor seemed not being happening. I replaced it by an `init()` method which then was called explicitly and so I got what I was expecting. Interestingly, the same code worked fine when loading the plugin dynamically. Thanks for sharing "I'm not used to seeing constructors or member variables in Qt plugins", I'm just in the beginning.